# get the index where the continuity breaks first time in python list

Tags: python

Suppose the python list is;
`my_list = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]`

The sequence of `0s` changes at the index position `5` of the list. Is there a way to return the index when a sequence is changed for the first time in a list?

Comment: If your list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, the result is 1 (from 1->2), right?

Comment: If you want to try out a solution: use zip() to zip your list with itself shifted by 1. You get pairs from that. Use an enumerate() on the pairs and find the first where the pairs differ. Output the index. Done.

Comment: @PatrickArtner That's a horribly inefficient solution.

Comment: @Selcuk why? The zipping produces a generator, the enumeration an enumerator - you can stop at the first possible difference. You can break as soon as you find a differece in pairs. It is worse then simply checking evenry element against the first  though, but you can use it to get _all_ flips from a to b as list of True/False for further work with it if you like

Comment: Hi Patrick, Actually, scenario comes in pandas DataFrame, where i have to check for records (1 row for 1 record, columns are time based) the breaks happening at the first time. So if i get the index, i will be able to get the time. i am trying to solve this using apply(), Instead of writing all stories and making confusion, i wrote it in a simple elegant format using list, I am pretty sure using numpy there will be a easy way to solve this. Which is why i tagged, Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: If you use pandas, you should have told us. There are _better_ options available in pandas. (Such as `shift`).

Comment: [why-would-a-question-thats-normally-too-broad-in-any-other-language-be-okay-in-python](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353940/why-would-a-question-thats-normally-too-broad-in-any-other-language-be-okay-i)

Comment: @DYZ, thanks, i was not aware of that it could be done in pandas, please explain me the process.

Comment: You already got (and accepted) an answer to the question that you asked. If you want an answer to another question, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `index` method.

```
my_list = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]

my_list.index(1)
>> 5
```

Assuming you only have binary elements in your list, `.index` returns the lowest index of the element you are looking for in the list and would be the equivalent to when the sequence changes.

Or if they are just a sequence of numbers, you can define a helper function to return the first break in sequence by comparing it to the first value.

```
def changed(li):
    start = li[0]
    change = [i for i in li if i != start][0]
    return li.index(change)

another_list = [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
idx = changed(another_list)

print('index of sequence change: {}\nvalue of sequence change: {}'.format(idx,another_list[idx]))

>>
index of sequence change: 3
value of sequence change: 0
```

Comment: Thanks, hope this index() will return when "1" comes first, i mean the first time continuity breaks.

Comment: ".index returns the lowest index of the element you are looking for in the list" Yes, it specifies in the answer.

Comment: Lowest index meaning also the one that comes first, I have added an example with `another_list` which should illustrate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following reports the index of the 0->1 discontinuity even if the sequence starts with a 1:

```
my_list1 = [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
my_list0 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]

zero = my_list1.index(0)
one = my_list1[zero:].index(1) + zero
#6

zero = my_list0.index(0)
one = my_list0[zero:].index(1) + zero
#5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list1 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]

def pattern_change(my_list):
    for x in range(1,len(my_list)):
        if my_list[0] != my_list[x]:
            break
    return x

print pattern_change(my_list1)
> 5
```